# Access elements within an array inside a object in Grunt

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

Im trying to use an array to use as files names in Grunt

I have an array looks like this.

```
var myElements = [
    'elementOne',
    'elementTwo',
    'elementThree'
]
```

I would like to access the elements within the array above like this but it doesn't work.

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      myElements[0] : '/scss/elementOne.scss',
      myElements[1] : '/scss/elementTwo.scss',
      myElements[2] : '/scss/elementTwo.scss',
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS won't allow you to use variables as keys in the way you want. I think the only way you can solve this is by defining the files object prior to the creation of the sass object.

```
var files = {};
files[myElements[0]] = '/scss/elementOne.scss';
files[myElements[1]] = '/scss/elementTwo.scss';
files[myElements[2]] = '/scss/elementTwo.scss';

sass: {
    dist: files
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/st60bge9/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var myElements = [
      'elementOne',
      'elementTwo',
      'elementThree'
    ];

  grunt.initConfig({
    myElements: myElements,

    sass: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          myElements[0] : '/scss/elementOne.scss',
          myElements[1] : '/scss/elementTwo.scss',
          myElements[2] : '/scss/elementTwo.scss',
        }
     }
  }
```

....